# Change title of secondactivity according to firstactivity

Tags: android, android-activity

I am starting an activity from my first activity for 2 reasons, create and edit.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
i.putExtra(RecipesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, info.id);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
```

And

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_CREATE);
```

I need to change my SecondActivity file's title either Create or Edit.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: My question is: "How can I change my secondactivity's title?"

Comment: Have You tried setTitle() based on incoming extra from onCreate() of second activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Change title of secondactivity according to firstactivity

you can send one more key to `SecondActivity` from first activity with intent to identify operation type for changing  second Activity title according to operation.

From First Activity:

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
   i.putExtra(RecipesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, info.id);
   i.putExtra("ACTION_TYPE", "act_edit");  //<<<< set Action type here
   startActivityForResult(i, ACTIVITY_EDIT);
```

and in second Activity check for `ACTION_TYPE` to set Activity title :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String action_type = intent.getStringExtra("ACTION_TYPE");
if(action_type.equals("act_edit")){

   // change Activity title for edit action
 } else if(....){

 }
 ...
```

Comment: Why not use setAction(Intent.ACTION_EDIT) and getAction() on the intent?

Comment: @dymmeh : OP is sending intent to custom Activity to identify the operation instead of sending intent to system for opening, editing,deleting any file or dir

Comment: Yeah i was thinking that he'd need to add an intent filter since he's directly calling the activity class but I guess that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the oncreate you can check to see if it is create or edit.  Depending on which it is you can use

setTitle("Create");

or

setTitle("Edit");